# Apache Camel XA rollback and store on failure queue

Tags: jpa, apache-camel, jms, jta, xa

I am starting to think this is impossible now so hopefully somebody can give me some guidance.

In Short, I have a Springboot application running apache camel routes, XA is configured using Atomikos and as far as I can tell all the XA specific configuration is as it should be. When a route executes I can see a message removed from the jms queue, a database insert is executed using a @Transacted JPA component and the message is routed to an output jms queue. All fine and I can see log information that supports the transaction manager committing both jms and JPA bits.

The issue comes when I have an exception, I need to be able to attempt re delivery 3 times and if that fails route the message on to a failure queue but not before the database insert is be rolled back.

I have a configured TransactionErrorHandlerBuilder which is setting the redelivery count to 3 and also managing the RedeliveryDelay, I can see all of that working but I never manage to divert the message after 3 delivery attempts to the route that I have setup to deliver to the failure queue. I have set the DeadLetterUri to point to the route but it seems that the transactionErrorHandler never makes use of it, camel just tries to redeliver the message 3 times over and over again until I kill the route.

Is what I am asking not supported? I am really hoping I am missing something obvious.

(Camel 2.19)
(SpringBoot 1.5.3)

thanks
Paul

Comment: Configure the message broker to do the redelivery and what dead letter queue to move the message to if all that fails - do not use Camel redelivery as its not the same.

Comment: Course! thank you, makes perfect sense.

Comment: Hi @PaulB, I'm interested in knowing how it worked out for you, I'm in similar boat. Do you have a poc of this solution? I would like to learn from your exp.